# How to convert recognize a string as a Unicode char?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-2.x

Suppose that there is a file that contains something like the
following, is there a way in python to recognize as the corresponding Unicode
chars instead of two strings starting with "0x"? (Both python 2 and 3 solutions are needed if they are different.) Thanks.

```
0x2591
0x2592
```

Comment: Neither interpretation is more correct than the other. You are free to see individual bytes `0`, `x`, `2`, `5`, etc, and you are equally free to interpret the sequence `0x2591` as the string representation of a single integer value representing a Unicode code point.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> chr(int('0x2591'[2:], 16))
'░'
```

In other words, cut the `0x` off (`[2:]`), evaluate it as an integer with base 16 (`int(,16)`), then convert it from a codepoint into a string (`chr()`).